# express integrals as limits

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

How would you go about expressing the following as a limit?
$$\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx$$ 
I know how to express limits on simple equations, but have no clue how to go about expressing an integral as a limit.

Do I need to expand it as if I was performing a normal integration?

Comment: It's an improper integral. Do you understand why? Do you see where the singularity is? Do you know the definition of an improper integral in terms of limits, having something to do with the singularity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This integral with unbounded integrand is improper at $x = 0,$ but it converges.

So

$$\int_0^1 \ln x \, dx = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_c^1 \ln x \, dx = \lim_{c \to 0}( x \ln x - x)|_c^1 = -1.$$

It also can be computed as the limit of a right-hand Riemann sum even though it is not properly Riemann integrable

$$\int_0^1 \ln x \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \ln (k/n) = \ln \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}\right) = \ln(e^{-1}) = -1.$$

This is generally true for improper integrals with monotone integrands.

Answer (score 1):

Since Riemann integration is only defined for bounded functions, technically the integral $$\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx$$ is not properly defined from the outset; we need to come up with a new definition for it. We see that $\ln(x)$ is bounded on any interval of the form $[\epsilon, 1]$ for $0 < \epsilon < 1$ so $\int_\epsilon^1 \ln(x) dx$ is properly defined for any such $\epsilon$. Hence, if the limit exists, we can define $$\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx := \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1 \ln(x) dx$$ and if the limit does not exist, we can declare the integral to be divergent (here you will find that that limit exists).

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts

$$= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} x \ln(x) |_\epsilon^1 - \int_0^1 1 \: \text{dx}$$

$$= -\left ( \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \epsilon \ln(\epsilon) \right) - \int_0^1 1 \: \text{dx}$$

$$= -1$$